The variation price isn't showing on the product page
When I go to a product page the price isn't shown. When logged in as admin I see 'This block is broken or missing. You may be missing content or you might need to install the original module.' and the logs contain 'The "field_block:commerce_product_variation:physical:price" was not found'
In manage layout for the product add block doesn't show any of the product variation fields.
I've compared my site to the Drupal Commerce Kickstart project on which this site is built and cannot find any differences in the configuration which might have caused this.
Any ideas what might be causing this?

Check if you have the module "Layout Builder Expose All Field Blocks" installed.
I encountered the same problem as described above. I had recently uninstalled the module layout_builder_expose_all_field_blocks because it has been marked as deprecated.
After re-installing this deprecated module I can again add price and other product variation fields to the layout.
Keep in mind though that you may not see the module from the module list in the extension GUI; I had to re-install the module with drush.

The module was listed and enabling it solved the problem. Thank you very much for  your help.

This worked for me after re-enabling the module "Layout Builder Expose All Field Blocks". I 'd rather not leave it active since it's deprecated, but for now, blocks are displayed again. Thank You!
